Как конвертировать файлы из docx в pdf на python
Никак не могу найти подходящее решение по конвертированию из docx в pdf.
Проблема в том, что я это делаю на хостинге, где у меня нет возможности дать команду sudo и установить какие-то приложения. Поэтому получается что я могу пользоваться только пакетами python.
Пробовал настроить doc2pdf, но на хочет чтобы я поставил LibreOffice, чего я сделать не могу.
Пробовал aspose-words, но она требует OpenSSL который я тоже не могу установить.
Пробовал spare.doc, все отлично но огромная надпись на каждой странице что версия не оплаченная. Я бы и рад оплатить, но вообще не пойму как. Тем более это зарубежная компания, они все деньги из РФ не принимают.
Пробовал найти какой-нибудь сервис для конвертации чтобы отправить файл по api и конвертировать. Но тоже находятся только буржуйские, которым непонятно как деньги оплатить.
Понятно, что можно купить выделеный сервер чтобы там ставить что захочется, но моих познаний не хватает чтобы полноценно развернуть сервер с нуля. Тем более что вопрос-то в общем-то мелкий...
Подскажите, какой может быть вариант решения?


https://www.online-convert.com/ru - бесплатно.
Microsoft Word легко и просто сохраняет документы в pdf.


Ну я видел сервис online-convert.com/ru, там бесплатно только 30 каких-то кредитов. А потом надо их покупать, но когда я ввожу данные карты, сайт пишет что карта отклонена.
А по поводу Word я не очень понял... Мне надо чтобы это делал питон на хостинге. Причем я не могу там какие-то приложения устанавливать. Как это сделать с помощью Word?


online-convert.com/ru: если массово, много, то конечно, бесплатный сыр бывает только в мышеловке. Я пользуюсь, когда речь идёт о нескольких файлах. По поводу почему нельзя заплатить, уверен, объяснять не надо.
Microsoft Word  может нативно сохранять документы в pdf. А чтоб "само и много", надо программировать. Если в процессе задействованы docx и pdf, то без "хозяев", естественно, обойтись нельзя. doc2pdf я лично не пробовал, нет нужды (сам Ворд, как я уже говорил, сохранять может), но если Ворд установлен, работать должен как бы.


Больше вариантов мне мой "приятель-инкогнито" не подсказал.

Я сомневаюсь, что найдётся какая-то бибилиотека, которая сможет хорошо преобразовать (распечатать) docx  в pdf. Поэтому лучше использовать Word с помощью interops-библиотеки. Есть ещё Open/LibreOffice. Если там нет сохранения в pdf, то нужно установить в системе pdf-принтер. Тогда можно с командной строки распечатать документ.

"поставил LibreOffice, чего я сделать не могу" - есть же portable версия.

Зависит от документа и навыков. Я - очень опытный пользователь Word. Опустим подробности. Справочные руководства, в качестве примера, я готовлю как документы Word, а потом сохраняю их в pdf. И у меня всё ок - оглавление, картинки, таблицы, графики и прочее. Возможно, я когда-нибудь от скуки потестирую doc2pdf. Сомневаюсь, что увижу что-то из ряд вон выходящее. Его не должно быть. Потому что вордом же и сохраняется документ в pdf. Я подобное сам писал, когда программировал с помощью языков МС. Создаётся объект Word.Application и далее уже што хош.

Вот ещё по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python

Подход с портативным LibreOffice подошел. Только возникла проблема: почему-то он сбрасывает все настройки, не понимает таблицы и оставляет только одну страницу. Как с этим быть?
Использовал дистрибутив вот отсюда: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/

@FoxFox настоящие профи справку генерируют скриптом при коммите.

Это о чём? Ни о чём. Набор красивых слов на птичьем. Моё решение тут тоже есть. А Ваше?

Я протестировал модуль docx2pdf. Хотите правильный результат? Установите современный MS Office 2024, если не хотите иметь постоянные сюрпризы с конвертацией. Какие-то левые устаревшие офисы, всякие там либре-офисы, неизвестно какие - в сад. Не иначе! Для работы со сложным современным документом модуль требует наличия современного MS Office. Я только что конвертировал достаточно сложный файл справки, с оглавлением, картинками, разбиением на страницы. Результат: один к одному, ни одной ошибки. Вот скриптик:
import os

print("-" * 50 + "\nКонвертация .docx в .pdf:\n" + "-" * 50)

ok = True

try: import docx2pdf
except Exception as e: print(f"Ошибка импорта модуля! Подробнее:\n{e}"); ok = False

if ok:
 input_file = "help.docx"
 output_file = "help.pdf"

 if not os.path.exists(input_file): print(f"Файл {input_file} не найден! Выполнение конвертации невозможно!")
 else: docx2pdf.convert(input_file, output_file)

print("Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")

И другой вариант решения - макрос для выполнения в Microsoft Word. В заданный каталог складываются файлы .docx, которые нужно конвертировать в .pdf. Запускается макрос и всё конвертируется, файлы .pdf образуются в этом же каталоге. Результат ожидаемо отличный. Код макроса:
Sub ConvertDocsToPDF()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim doc As Document

folderPath = "d:\downloads\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.docx")
    
If fileName = "" Then
 MsgBox "В каталоге нет файлов .docx для конвертации!", vbExclamation
 Exit Sub
End If

Do While fileName <> ""
 Set doc = Documents.Open(folderPath & fileName, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
 doc.SaveAs2 folderPath & Replace(fileName, ".docx", ".pdf"), wdFormatPDF
 doc.Close False
 fileName = Dir()
 Loop

MsgBox "Все документы конвертированы в PDF!", vbInformation
End Sub

